# How to return namespaces by regex in clojure?

Tags: regex, clojure

Suppose I want to unmap all the namespaces loaded in my repl `(all-ns)` that match the regex `myproject\..*stuff`. So I want to do something like `(unmap #"myproject\..*stuff")`, which doesn't work because unmap takes functions and not regexes.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
(->> (all-ns) (mapcat #(ns-publics %)) (map second))
```

Gives you a list of all symbols across all namespaces.
Next steps, add a filter for the var's you want unmapped and then call `(ns-unmap)`